How do I delete a column meeting specific criteria in Perl?
I have the following table
head  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
stn2   1   4   1   1   4   2
stn2   1   4   1   1   4   2
stn3   1   4   1   1   4   2
stn4   1   4   1   1   4   3
stn4   1   4   1   1   4   2
stn5   1   4   1   1   4   4
stn6   1   3   1   1   4   3
stn7   4   4   1   1   4   4
stn8   4   4   1   1   4   3
stn9   2   4   1   1   4   3

I would like to delete all columns containing 1's only. I have put the six columns in arrays with the following lengthy code;
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

open(my $RSKF, " < ../risks.txt") || die "open risks.txt: failed $! ($^E)";
my $line;
my $count;

my @one_column;
my @two_column;
my @three_column;
my @four_column;
my @five_column;
my @six_column;

my $one_column;
my $two_column;
my $three_column;
my $four_column;
my $five_column;
my $six_column;

my @remove;
my @keep1;
my $keepcount=0;

while($line = <$RSKF>){
push(@one_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[2]);
push(@two_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[3]);
push(@three_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[4]);
push(@four_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[5]);
push(@five_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[6]);
push(@six_column, (split(/\s+/, $line))[7]);
 }

My attempt to loop through the fourth column below does not work.
$count=0;
for (my $i=1; $i < @four_column; ++$i){
if($four_column[$i] ge '2'){
$count++;
}
if($count > 0){
@four_column=@keep1;
$keepcount++;
}
else{
@four_column=@remove;
}

}
Surely there should be an easier way of doing this. Please help.

Reading each column into a separate variable is weird and clumsy. Building a list of lists is both more flexible and general, and easier for this use case.

Tip: Repeated code is a sign of bad code. If you find yourself creating variables for the form foo_number or number_foo, you should be using an array. Also, there's no reason to split the line six times!

To output a filtered table:
perl -lae '
    push @rows, [@F];
    next if $.==1;

    for (keys @F) {
        $wanted[$_] = 1 if $F[$_]!=1;
    }

    END {
        @cols = grep {$wanted[$_]} keys @F;
        for (@rows) {
            print join "\t", @$_[@cols]; 
        }
    }
' original.txt >new.txt


autosplit each row into columns and store
if a column has value != 1 then it is wanted (don't check first row)
after all rows have been processed, print wanted columns of each row


Thank you very much @jhnc, this does exactly what I want to and works perfectly. I really appreciate.

Sorry to come @jhnc. When I run the code on the command line it works perfectly. But I want to run it in a script. When I do that I get the error "String found where operator expected at ./07_write_risks.pl line 32, near "} '"
(Might be a runaway multi-line '' string starting on line 20)
(Missing semicolon on previous line?)
and "Bareword "perl" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./07_write_risks.pl line 32". I tried to run the code as a system command "system(/usr/bin/perl 'thecode). The result is worse. I will appreeciate your help.

@Zilore Mumba, This is a shell command, not Perl code. You can't just insert a shell command in the middle of Perl code and expect it to work! Very easy to convert into Perl code, though.

line 32? Are you trying to embed this as part of another bigger program?

Once more sorry for my blunder, it works when run inside a bash script.
